PyFlink Failure enricher
We are using PyFlink for our data stream processing pipeline.
Looking for a way to handle failures globally. There is a FailureEnricher in the Java implementation.
I came across this code in an example
from pyflink.util.failure_enricher import FailureEnricher

class MyCustomFailureEnricher(FailureEnricher):
    def enrich(self, failure):
        # Custom logic to handle the failure
        print("A failure occurred:", failure)

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.add_failure_enricher(MyCustomFailureEnricher())

However this class from pyflink.util.failure_enricher import FailureEnricher is not available in the apache-flink version 1.19 of pyflink.
What are we missing and which version of pyflink has support for FailureEnrichers?
